# Split table names in Python

Tags: python

I have some table names like below in `python`

```
table1='123_test_abc_de'
table2='123_test_10_abc_de'
table3='123_red_ce'
table4='123_utc'
```

Now from this list I want to split the tables like below

```
abc_de
abc_de
red_ce
utc
```

I have tried like below

```
repo=table.split("_", 1)[-1]
```

I got the following result for each table

```
test_abc_de
test_10_abc_de
red_ce
utc
```

How can I achieve what I want.

Comment: Probably with a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table is a list of strings like you say it is:

```
map(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[-2:]),table)
```

will give you a list of new strings like you want. Also I just found 'rsplit':

```
map(lambda x: '_'.join(x.rsplit('_',2)[-2:]),table)
```

For a single such string in a variable just use `rsplit`:

```
'_'.join(table1.rsplit('_',2)[-2:])
```

**Long string**

If all of your table names are contained in a long string, separated by space, then you just need to split that string:

```
map(lambda x: '_'.join(x.rsplit('_',2)[-2:]),tableNamesString.split())
```

Comment: Actually table is a `string` not list of `strings`

Comment: @Virureddy I updated my answer to solve for a long string. It's unclear from your question what you actually have, where are the names coming from. Once you have a single name `rsplit` will do the job though. If this still isn't what you looked for please amend your question and be specific how you're retrieving the names, or in what kind of data type are you holding them. If you have one name in a different variable (which would be very odd) than you need to `rsplit` each.